# Programming code listing: enumeration and left margin

Tags: verbatim, line-numbering

I'd like to include programming codes in LaTeX by using the `verbatim` package.
For the code I use, the enumeration is continuous.
So if a new code starts, the numbers are ongoing, which should not be the case.
The use of the `linenumbers` package did not help.

Further I'd like to have a vertical line between the numbers and the code to indicate the left margin.

I have attached the code.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{linenumbers}
    \begin{verbatim}
    function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
    % This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
    % interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
    % 
    % Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
    % 
    % Where,
    %  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
    %  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
    %  a= Initial point of interval
    %
    \end{verbatim}
  \end{linenumbers}
  NO NUMBERS SHOULD APPEAR HERE, THE NUMBERS SHOULD START IN THE NEXT LINE\\
  \begin{linenumbers}
    \begin{verbatim}
    function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
    % This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
    % interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
    % 
    % Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
    % 
    % Where,
    %  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
    %  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
    %  a= Initial point of interval
    \end{verbatim}
  \end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My `verbatimbox` package can do this.  However, I had to renew the `verbnobox` environment in order to not reset the line number counter (I'll be fixing this in a future release of the package).  To reset the line number manually, `\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}`.

In this MWE, I set the line number in `\scriptsize` and the code in `\small`, both of which can be altered in the definition of `\tmp`.  The variable which I define as `\tmp` is key to setting the content and appearance of the verbatim as well as its marginal heading.

EDITED to guarantee that new environment picks up on sequential line number where count was last left off.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
\renewenvironment{verbnobox}{%
%  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \let\my@par\par%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
\verbatim\verbbox@inner%
}
{%
  \endverbatim%
  \global\def\@tmp{}%
  \addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{\makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\theVerbboxLineNo\ \smash{%
  \rule[-1.4\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{1.4\baselineskip}}\ }\small}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
% interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
%
\end{verbnobox}
NO NUMBERS SHOULD APPEAR HERE, THE NUMBERS SHOULD START IN THE NEXT LINE
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the  interval 
[a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
\end{verbnobox}
RESET LINE NUMBERS
\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
Reset Line Numbers should appear here
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the features provided by `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document} 

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
% interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or avector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
%
\end{Verbatim}
NO NUMBERS SHOULD APPEAR HERE, THE NUMBERS SHOULD START IN THE NEXT LINE
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,firstnumber=last]
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the  interval 
[a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding a rule is more complicated.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{NVerbatim}{Verbatim}{%
  numbers=left,
  firstnumber=last,
  numbersep=4pt,
}
\preto\NVerbatim{\let\FV@Numbers@left=\matthias@Numbers@left}
\def\matthias@add@rule{%
  \ifx\FV@FontSize\relax\normalsize\else\FV@FontSize\fi
  \kern\FV@NumberSep\strut\vrule
}
\def\matthias@Numbers@left{%
  \let\FV@RightListNumber\relax
  \def\FV@LeftListNumber{%
  \@tempcnta=\FV@CodeLineNo
  \@tempcntb=\FV@CodeLineNo
  \divide\@tempcntb\FV@StepNumber
  \multiply\@tempcntb\FV@StepNumber
  \ifnum\@tempcnta=\@tempcntb
      \if@FV@NumberBlankLines
        \hbox to\z@{\hss\theFancyVerbLine\,\matthias@add@rule\kern\FV@NumberSep}%
      \else
        \ifx\FV@Line\empty
        \else
          \hbox to\z@{\hss\theFancyVerbLine\,\matthias@add@rule\kern\FV@NumberSep}%
        \fi
      \fi
  \fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{NVerbatim}
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
% interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or avector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
%
\end{NVerbatim}
NO NUMBERS SHOULD APPEAR HERE, THE NUMBERS SHOULD START IN THE NEXT LINE
\begin{NVerbatim}
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
% interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
% 
% Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
% 
% Where,
%  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
%  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
%  a= Initial point of interval
\end{NVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For restarting the numbering, call

```
\begin{NVerbatim}[firstnumber=1]
```

Comment: thanks @egreg, do you know how to add the vertical line between the code and the numbers ? (2nd part of the question)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not restrict yourself only to the `verbatim` package, you can alternatively use the package `listings` which allows you to use code line enumeration automatically.

For this package the same question has been raised and answered successfully: [What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75116/25077)

Minimal working code example (MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=Matlab,%
        numbers=left, % display line numbers at the left margin
        numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}}, % size of the numbers
        numbersep=9pt % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
}

\begin{document}

% Include Matlab file
\lstinputlisting{simpsons.m}

% Include Matlab code directly
\begin{lstlisting}
    function I = simpsons(f, a, b, n)
    % This function computes the integral "I" via Simpson's rule in the
    % interval [a,b] with n+1 equally spaced points
    % 
    % Syntax: I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
    % 
    % Where,
    %  f= can be either an anonymous function (e.g. f=@(x) sin(x)) or a vector
    %  containing equally spaced values of the function to be integrated
    %  a= Initial point of interval
    %
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output result]